# Looking for someone who has done Magento 1.9 + Fishbowl API Gift cards

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, gift-card

We are currently having issues with giftcard transactions inside fishbowl coming from magento.

Magento processes the order, then sends the order over to fishbowl. In which fishbowl classifies the giftcard as a discount. Fishbowl then believes it is an underpayment and then double charges for shipping and causes a mess.

Is there anyone who has developed a magento site that has fishbowl inventory as a connection, and also who has gift cards working properly? Fishbowl Inventory has nothing to say and said to seek outside help.

We are using the WebTex giftcard, but can easily switch to Amasty or anything like that if we are able to get any ideas on what to do to fix this.